# which version of Bamboo CI compatible with java 6,7 and 8

Tags: java-8, sonarqube, bamboo

Currently we are using Bamboo 4.4.0 which supports both java 6 and java 7.Since we are upgrading SONARQUBE server which is integrated with Bamboo to version 5.6 which runs only in Java 8. We are looking for Bamboo version which is compatible with Java 6,7 and 8 as we have some old java application as well.Any help or pointer will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by support Java 6,7,8 etc?

If you're interested in Bamboo version which can run on Java 6,7 and 8, then there is no officially supported version with such capabilities.

If you need Bamboo to build applications using JDK 1.6, 1.7 etc, then you can use any Bamboo, executable capabilities doesn't depend on Java version used to start Bamboo

Comment: I am wondering what made you downcast my question..i asked a very simple question for example if we use bamboo 4.4.0 i can have jdk7 as additonal java so is it possible to have java 8 similarly as well.bamboo 5.x+  version do not support java 6 and 7 and hence my question. i see the response as a very pathetic way to guide somebody.

Comment: Bamboo 5.13 supports building of application with any Java. You need Java 8 to run Bamboo and then use any version of JDK to build your code inside